# Additon of complex numbers using operator overloading in c++

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading, overloading

Not able to understand a block of code in below given program.
Especially the variable, temp which has return type as the complex(the class name) and when we return the variable, temp where it gets returned to?
That is  `return(temp);` in the program.

**The Program**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class complex
{
public:
    complex();//default constructors
    complex(float real, float imag)//constructor for setting values
    {
        x = real;
        y = imag;
    }
    complex operator +(complex);
    void display(void);
    ~complex();

private:
    float x;
    float y;

};

complex::complex()
{
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
complex complex::operator+(complex c)
{
    complex temp;
    temp.x = x + c.x;
    temp.y = y + c.y;
    return(temp);
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void complex::display(void) {
    cout << x << "+j" << y << "/n";

}

complex::~complex()
{
}


int main()
{
    complex C1, C2, C3,C4;
    C1 = complex(1, 3.5);//setting of first number
    C2 = complex(2,2.7);//setting of second number
    C4 = complex(2, 5);

    C3 = C1 + C2+C4;//operator overloading
    cout << "C1 = ";
    C1.display();
    cout << "\n C2 = ";
    C2.display();
    cout << "\n C4 = ";
    C4.display();
    cout << "\n C3 = ";
    C3.display();

    system("pause");

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but with [the generally bad `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) then you should consider to *not* name your class the same as [the standard `std::complex` class template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex).

Comment: As for your problem, if we look at the usage of the `+` operator, lets say we have (the more simple) `C3 = C1 + C2`, then that's the same as `C3 = C1.operator+(C2)`. Does that help you?

Answer (score 0):

```
complex C5;
C5=C1+C2;
```

means

```
C5=C1.operator+(C2)
```

equivalent to

```
complex temp;
temp.x = x + C2.x; /* x=C1.x*/
temp.y = y + C2.y; /* y=C1.y*/
C5=temp;
```

Comment: You're missing a quite important part there... Where's `C1`?

Comment: @madhurachanna, in an operator, the host class is the first operand (C1) and the second class is the argument (C2) to the operator.

Comment: But i heard we don't need to give C1 because it implicit  .. And after executing i got  the required answer......

Comment: You don't need to write `C1.operator+(C2)` but `C1+C2` is exactly equivalent to it.